# listagg(distinct column) over()

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Any idea of alternatives to `listagg(distinct column) over()` that are supported- something to NOT be grouping by the rest of the columns? I have 20+..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery with `row_number()` to identify the first value to include in the `listagg()`, such as:

```
select listagg(case when seqnum = 1 then column end) within group (order by column) over (order by ?)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by column order by column) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```